# Traducción en español del termino "build"

Tags: ensamblador, compilador

¿Cuál sería la castellanización del termino ***build*** en programación? Hasta donde sé, es usado ***cuando un compilador compila*** algo, pero no es lo mismo, por que cuando trabajas con un ***ensamblador*** y ***ensamblas*** algo, también se le dice ***build***. A lo mejor no estoy entendiendo el verdadero significado de esta expresión. ¿Cómo se traduciría?. No creo que sea ***construir***.

Comment: Yo lo traduciría como **pulsar el botón del engranaje** XD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El "build", ya sea mediante la compilación de recursos, o mediante el ensamblado, se refiere a recopilar todos los recursos del proyecto y "montar" (construir) un único archivo, o al menos los archivos indispensables para la ejecución.

Creo que lo más normal es traducirlo como "compilar", pero "ensamblar" o "construir" también serían correctas. Creo que el término más usado a día de hoy es "compilar" debido a que ya muy poca gente programa en ensamblador.

Comment: Es cierto, ya nadie programa en ensamblador, sin embargo si es importante saber al menos un poco, por que creo yo que te da mejor entendimiento de como programar mejor en alto nivel. Luego la gente programa sin tener una ligera idea de como funciona en verdad los registros y las memorias en la computadora, y que no puedes hacer lo que se te de la gana y usar las capacidades y limitantes que el hardware tiene como si no importaran

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, saber ensamblador siempre es bueno.

Answer (score 3):

En programación, la palabra **build** significa "*construir*", en el sentido de *precompilar*, *compilar*, *ensamblar*, *enlazar*, *empaquetar código*, etc. Por lo general se usa cuando se toma el código fuente y se genera todo el código objeto, máquina, interpretable, módulo, script o lo que sea que corresponda. en términos informáticos es más acertado *compilar* no importa si estas usando un lenguaje de alto nivel (como Python) o un lenguaje de bajo nivel (como ensamblador) porque no "*ensamblas*", sino que compilas el programa

Comment: Si, pero en realidad esta mal dicho. Si se dice ensamblar, pero al parecer fue un error que se propago. Mira lo que dijo un programador: "Excuse me for intrusion. But it seems to me the assembler code should be "assembled", not "compiled" by terminology. The compilation process is a prerogative of higher level languages like ANSI C. At last the name of software utilities says that: an Assembler and the Compiler. Still can't hear the "compilation" about assembler code without a pain. Sorry."

Comment: y todos están acuerdos con eso: "I fully agree however I gave up a long time ago trying to get the correct terminology used consistently, the "coders" will win out in the end anyway......"

Comment: Bueno, en ese caso entonces lo mejor sería usar *build* que, como explique arriba, significa compilar y ensamblar. De todas formas, si todavía tienes duda, puedes publicar tu pregunta aquí [spanish language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

`build` literalmente se traduce como "Construir", pero en programacion `build` tambien es `compilar`

Comment: Pero esta mal dicho. Esto es lo que un programador de habla inglesa dijo en un foro discutiendo sobre la terminología: I also gave up on correcting others on that terminology.  "Assembler assembles, compiler compiles, and both can "build"." En teoría compilar no es lo mismo que construir